# 2 column css for eBook

Tags: css, ipad, overflow, epub

I have written a html file with css, I want 2 columns in the eBook, since the text is too large.But the text from second column is displayed on the second page at the first column position.Can anybody tell me why is tho happening.

Comment: You're probably going to need to show some markup if you want this answered.

Comment: can any one suggest some epub files which are having two columns in it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create epub with fixed layout to achieve this. Following is the link which should help you creating epub with fixed layout from scratch :

http://epubsecrets.com/getting-started-with-fixed-layout-epubs.php

And below is the book created by this author:

http://www.fantasycastlebooks.com/resources/Theft%20of%20the%20Rhinegold%20-%20iBooks%20Edition.epub